# Has support Doctrine Sluggable Unique_base option multiple fields?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a post table like as

```
id  slug title  content  objectKey  objectId
```

I want generate slugs unique by 3 field. `[ title, objectKey, objectId ]`

How could make it ?

Comment: I know this is an old topic.
but if someone is still looking for this, please try unique_base option. https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/sluggable.md#some-other-configuration-options-for-slug-annotation

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine Sluggable from DoctrineExtension supports multiple fields.

For details look at:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md
and search:

```php
    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title", "code"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;
```

If ObjectId is a relation take a look at:

```php
/**
 * Person domain object class
 *
 * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Slug(handlers={
 *      @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\RelativeSlugHandler", options={
 *          @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationField", value="category"),
 *          @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationSlugField", value="title"),
 *          @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="/"),
 *          @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SlugHandlerOption(name="urilize", value=true)
 *      })
 * }, fields={"title", "code"})
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(length=64, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

Comment: Thankyou but i don't want change slug as / title-objectId  i want only check bases as unique slug generation.

Comment: Can you make any example?